# how to clear .txt file contents without delete file in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to clear .txt file contents; the file name is stored in the variable       `$data['soft_files']` which is taken by a button and sent to the controller from javascript.

```
$data['soft_files'] = $this->input->post('soft_files'); 
$file = FCPATH . "/software_files/$this->input->post('soft_files')";
file_put_contents ($file, "");
```

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, "");` is not working how?

Comment: should be like `$file = FCPATH . "software_files/".$this->input->post('soft_files'); `note / after FCPATH

Comment: `"/software_files/$this->input->post('soft_files')";` *might* want some curly braces there `"/software_files/{$this->input->post('soft_files')}";` - it might work as-is, I've not checked, but it seems safer to use the `{ ... }`